# Can't find the mainActivity file

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am using `IntelliJ IDEA CE` to code an `Android` app and, when creating a new project, I don't have the `mainActivity` file. I also can't find the `layouts` folder.

I'm following [this site](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project) and according to it I should have:

- app > java > com.example.myfirstapp > MainActivity
- app > res > layout > activity_main.xml

This is what my project folder looks like:
[image: my folders inside the android project]

I have already tried searching for `mainActivity` with `cmd+shift+O`, but these are not what I'm looking for.

My search results: 
[image: search results]

If any one could explain why these files are not there it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The tutorial you are following uses Android Studio. I'd suggest you to check it once

Comment: It looks like you selected not the option "Empty activity" but "Add No Activity"